# How to add label to address field in magento customer address?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, adminhtml

I want to add address field label to address field 2 in Magento admin panel. I want to add label House number in customer address field where Address will be in address line 1 and the new label will be in address line 2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

create customer attribute form admin and you can achieve functionality that you want

here is the magento doc guide to add customer attribute

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/customers/customer-attributes-create.html

Hope this will help you and let me know if you have any doubut

Comment: Its for EE and I am working on CE. Hence wont work with CE